# Github project can't open

Tags: android, github

I'm getting this issue while I import github project
This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2021.1.1 or newer.  how to solve this issue

Comment: Did you try doing what the error suggests and upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Because the gradle.properties of the project is not compatible with your android studio version... I Suggest click on **Windows>Check For Updates** and download all the files !!